# Material toolbar for AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart-html, dart-webui

Material toolbar for Angular2.
Error: [Error from TemplateCompiler on my_app|lib/app_header/app_header.ng_meta.json]:
Could not find Directive/Pipe entry for name: MaterialToolbarComponent
. Please be aware that Dart transformers have limited support for reusable, pre-defined lists of Directives/Pipes (aka "directive/pipe aliases"). See for details
Build completed with 1 errors.

1. error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:material_toolbar/material_toolbar.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [my_app] lib\app_header\app_header.dart:6)
2. error: The values in a const list literal must be constants. (non_constant_list_element at [my_app] lib\app_header\app_header.dart:15)
3. error: Undefined name 'MaterialToolbarComponent'. (undefined_identifier at [my_app] lib\app_header\app_header.dart:15)
4. error: Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. (const_with_non_constant_argument at [my_app] lib\app_header\app_header.dart:15)

app-header.html

```
<header role="banner" id="header">
    <material-toolbar [background]="background" [foreground]="foreground" [elevation]="elevation" [icon]="icon"
                      [title]="title" [middleTitle]="middleText" [bottomTitle]="bottomText" [mediumTall]="size == 'medium'"
                      [tall]="size == 'tall'">
        <div class="right-content">
            <material-button icon>
                <glyph icon="refresh"></glyph>
            </material-button>
            <material-button icon>
                <glyph icon="add"></glyph>
            </material-button>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-content">
            <material-input></material-input>
            <material-button icon>
                <glyph icon="search"></glyph>
            </material-button>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-content">
            <material-button icon>
                <glyph icon="content_cut"></glyph>
            </material-button>
            <material-button icon>
                <glyph icon="content_copy"></glyph>
            </material-button>
            <material-button icon>
                <glyph icon="content_paste"></glyph>
            </material-button>
        </div>
        <material-progress class="fit" [indeterminate]="true"></material-progress>
    </material-toolbar>
    <material-fab [style.background-color]="background" raised>
        <glyph icon="search" [style.color]="foreground"></glyph>
    </material-fab>
    <div id="content">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="size">
            <material-radio [checked]="true" value="standard">
                Standard
            </material-radio>
            <material-radio value="medium">
                Medium-Tall
            </material-radio>
            <material-radio value="tall">
                Tall
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
        <br/>
        <material-input floatingLabel label="Title" [(ngModel)]="title"></material-input>
        <br/>
        <material-input *ngIf="size == 'medium' || size == 'tall'" floatingLabel label="Middle Text"
                        [(ngModel)]="middleText"></material-input>
        <br/>
        <material-input *ngIf="size == 'tall'" floatingLabel label="Bottom Text" [(ngModel)]="bottomText"></material-input>
        <br/>
        <material-input floatingLabel label="Toolbar Icon" [(ngModel)]="icon"></material-input>
        <br/>
        <material-input floatingLabel label="Background Color" [(ngModel)]="background"></material-input>
        <br/>
        <material-input floatingLabel label="Foreground Color" [(ngModel)]="foreground"></material-input>
        <br/>
        <label>Elevation: {{elevation}}</label>
        <material-button raised primary (click)="up()">
            <glyph icon="add"></glyph>
        </material-button>
        <material-button raised [disabled]="elevation <= 0" (click)="down()">
            <glyph icon="remove"></glyph>
        </material-button>
    </div>
</header>
```

app-header.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:material_toolbar/material_toolbar.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'app-header',
  styleUrls: const ['app_header.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_header.html',
  directives: const [
    CORE_DIRECTIVES,
    materialDirectives,
    MaterialToolbarComponent,
  ],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppHeader {

  int elevation = 2;
  String background = '#3f51b5',
      foreground = 'white',
      icon = 'menu',
      title = 'Material Toolbar Example';
  String middleText = 'Middle Text', bottomText = 'Bottom Text';
  String size = 'standard';

  void up() {
    elevation++;
  }

  void down() {
    if (elevation > 0) elevation--;
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message `'package:material_toolbar/material_toolbar.dart'. ` seems to indicate a `pub serve` issue perhaps related to WebStorm/IntelliJ. Can you please try if you get the same errors for `pub build`.

Comment: Yes the error is same for pub build

Comment: When you run `pub get`, do you get an error message, or does it succeed?

Comment: Now it worked I have run pub get pub serve 3-4 times.s

Comment: Great. I don't know what causes it, but similar problems were reported recently several times.

Comment: Again an error, this time running pub get, pub serve, builds the app successfully but doesn't reloads the page

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: It was building successfully without any error.It is running now i don't know how it's running by running the pub commands several times

Comment: Has your issue here been resolved?

Comment: Yes, the issue was resolved.